# Unpermitted Parameters when working with EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ember.js, rails-api

I'm trying to learn how to use emberjs as a client of a rails api!

My code lives here: https://github.com/brunoocasali/ember-n-rails

Is a simple rails-api that provides CRUD operations by the restful endpoints.
I'm following [this tutorial](http://9elements.com/io/index.php/an-ember-js-application-with-a-rails-api-backend/) but when I try to save a comment in blog post, I receive a `Unpermitted params: :post`.

**UPDATE 01**

```
Started POST "/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-01 10:01:01 -0200
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"comment"=>{"author"=>" asdasdasdas", "body"=>"dasdasd asd asd", "post"=>"1"}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Post(#29657520) expected, got String(#11585400)):
app/controllers/comments_controller.rb:13:in `create'


 Rendered /home/bruno/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (13.1ms)
 Rendered /home/bruno/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.7ms)
 Rendered /home/bruno/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
 Rendered /home/bruno/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (43.1ms)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What do your Ember models look like? What version of Ember are you using?

Comment: Sorry @Andrew I can't reproduce this error anymore!

Answer (score 0):

```
Unpermitted params: :post
```

Looking at this error, seems like you need to permit `post` in your strong param definition inside your `comments_controller.rb`. So, try this:

```
  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:author, :body, :post)
  end
```

Comment: Yeah, I've tried this but now I have some problems about the type, see: `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Post(#70253184677240) expected, got String(#11814760)):`. And don't works of course!!

Comment: yeah, so, its a different problem. Can you post the full error stack trace? and the corresponding controller action?